# FileBasedSource matching multiple patterns

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Assume I have following structure in Google Cloud Storage:

```
gs://bucket/
  aaa/
    file1.txt
    file2.txt
    ...
  aab/
    file1.txt
    file2.txt
    ...
  ...
  baa/
    file1.txt
    file2.txt
    ...
  ...
```

What's the best way to use `FileBasedSource` to read the *txt* files? I cannot use the glob patterns to match the files because I need to be able to select a range, e.g. I want to match all *txt* files in all directories in range `[aaz,baz]`. I also know that I can have multiple `PCollection<>` created using different sources and then merge them using the *Flatten* transform, however I'm not sure how the performance and dynamic work rebalancing would be affected if there would be too many of the `PCollection<>` coming from different sources.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use *TextIO* instead of *FileBasedSource* for a higher-level implementation. You can use FileIO.match() or matchAll() combined with FileIO.readMatches() and TextIO.readFiles().

Comment: This is a valid suggestion, but it doesn't answer my question. TextIO also uses filesystem glob for matching filepatterns which cannot be applied to my use-case.

Comment: You'll have to pick the correct set of files (using multiple globs) for the PCollection that is fed into FileIO.matchAll()